# Named parameter List<Long>, List<String> showing wrong expected type- Hibernate JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are using Hibernate 5 jars and when I send a list of string in named parameter value as part of HQL, I am unable to get the parameter value from Query for the param string. We are actually logging all params as part of interceptor.

HQL Query:SELECT test FROM test_table test where test.pkeyIN :pkeys

API Invoked throwing error- query.getParameterValue()

```
    Iterator<?> iter = query.getParameters().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Parameter param = (Parameter) iter.next();
            Object obj = null;
            try {
                obj =  query.getParameterValue(param);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.debug("****Exception*****" + e.getMessage());
            }

            query.setParameter(param.getName(), obj);
```

throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve QueryParameter reference [org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NamedParameterDescriptor@1e2e23b9] to QueryParameterBinding.

Did anyone get this issue before? Pls advice.

Comment: why not post the whole code, creating the query, setting the parameter on the query then getting the parameter value? If all is done in that order and you get an exception then you need to raise a bug on your JPA provider

Comment: Hibernate is the JPA provider. Updated question with code. Thanks.

Comment: so you set the parameter value AFTER calling getParameterValue?! i.e it has no value when you call getParameterValue

Comment: Yes I re-set the param(Without modification) after checking the actual value